# Mapping a simple 2 variable function

Tags: list-manipulation, graphics, functions, map, piecewise

Quick Question: What is the best way to map this function so it performs seperately for 102 different values of x?

```
tag[p_, x_] := Piecewise[{{Part[probeList, x], Norm[p - {5, 5} - Part[userEditedProbeCoordinates, x]] < 10}}]
Manipulate[Show[rttp, PlotLabel -> tag[p]], {{p, {0, 0}}, Locator}]
```

I want to map it to all values of x between 1 and 102, using my list "bigrange". So I was thinking I could use

```
Map[tag,bigrange]
```

but this obviously doesn't work since tag is applied to 2 variables.

Are there any other ways to approach this problem, or some clever solution?

Here is an example of code that works for the first 2, but not all 102.

```
tag[ppp_] := Piecewise[{{Part[probeList, 1], Norm[ppp - {5, 5} -Part[userEditedProbeCoordinates, 1]] < 10}, {Part[probeList, 2], Norm[ppp - {5, 5} - Part[userEditedProbeCoordinates, 2]] < 10} }]
Manipulate[Show[rttp, PlotLabel -> tag[ppp]], {{ppp, {0, 0}}, Locator}]
```

Thanks so much.

Comment: What should be the value of `p` for each `x`?

Comment: p doesn't change, the full code involving p is there.

Comment: So, `Manipulate[Show[rttp, PlotLabel -> tag[p, #]], {{p, {0, 0}}, Locator}] & /@ bigrange`?

Comment: Hm replacing my second line with that is doing the same thing, seems to have the same results. I don't have much experience with pure functions, should this work without further edits? `tag[p_, x_] := 
 Piecewise[{{Part[probeList, x], 
    Norm[p - {5, 5} - Part[userEditedProbeCoordinates, x]] < 10}}]
Manipulate[
   Show[rttp, PlotLabel -> tag[p, #]], {{p, {0, 0}}, 
    Locator}] & /@ bigrange`

Comment: Why not say what you are actually trying to do here?

Comment: Sorry, I need the function to be applied to a series of values of x, with p staying the same. So for example I could start off like this in a manual way, but I just need 102 of them. `tag[ppp_] := 
 Piecewise[{{Part[probeList, 1], 
    Norm[ppp - {5, 5} - Part[userEditedProbeCoordinates, 1]] < 
     10}, {Part[probeList, 2], 
    Norm[ppp - {5, 5} - Part[userEditedProbeCoordinates, 2]] < 10} }]
Manipulate[
 Show[rttp, PlotLabel -> tag[ppp]], {{ppp, {0, 0}}, Locator}] `

Comment: Does `tag[pVal, #]& /@ bigrange` work, where `pVal` is whatever constant value of `p` you want to use?

Comment: Thanks jjc, I just realised p is actually the position of the cursor in this function. Do you have any ideas for dealing with this?

Comment: And also using # and /@bigrange does work, it just gives the result of {0,0,0,0,0,0} etc before and after the number of interest.

Comment: Worked it out. Use `tag[p_] := 
 Piecewise[
  Table[{probeList[[i]], 
    Norm[p - {5, 5} - userEditedProbeCoordinates[[i]]] < 10}, {i, 
    bigrange}]]`

Comment: Kindly work on your question to make it clear as to what you want. For the code that you provide, start a fresh Mathematica and copy, paste and run your code. If it doesn't run for you (the current state), try to fix it so it will run.

Answer (score 1):

`Piecewise` basically uses an array, so you can put it with a `Table`. for example

```
val = Sort@RandomReal[1, 10]
step[x_] = Piecewise[Table[{i, val[[i - 1]] < x < val[[i]]}, {i, 2, 10}]];
Plot[step[x], {x, 0, 1}, GridLines -> {val, {}}]
```

> {0.254837, 0.27277, 0.302014, 0.339608, 0.504063, 0.567221, 0.826478, \
>   0.869325, 0.879442, 0.904477}

[image]